# How can I make admin form field ($form->addField()) use PageBuilder editor?

Tags: magento2, adminform, wysiwyg, page-builder, addfield

I'm using Amasty's Landing Pages extension. On the Landing Pages edit form there's a content field that uses the default WYSIWYG editor. I need to make this field use the PageBuilder editor instead. I do have PageBuilder enabled. Thanks.

This is the code that adds the field:

```
$layoutFieldset->addField(
        'layout_top_description',
        'editor',
            [
               'name' => 'layout_top_description',
               'label' => __('Top Description'),
               'title' => __('Top Description'),
               'style' => 'width:725px;height:360px',
               'force_load' => true,
               'config' => $this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig()
            ]
    );
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I am trying to achieve something similar.